# In reading documentation, I should be able to join a tuple I get an error

Tags: python

Relevant code:

```
for new_file_name in os.walk( ROOT_DIR ):
    new_file_name_string = str.join(new_file_name)
```

Error message:

```
new_file_name_string = str.join(new_file_name)
TypeError: descriptor 'join' for 'str' objects doesn't apply to a 'tuple' object
```

`new_file_name` is a tuple as you know.

Comment: Where in the documentation did it say this should work?

Comment: Do you mean something like `''.join(new_file_name)`?

Comment: Do you understand what `str.join()` notation mean?

Comment: Currently being discussed on meta. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412281/15497888

Answer (score 3):

`join` is an instance method, and so is intended to be invoked by the string used to join the elements of the tuple:

```
>>> new_file_name = ("foo", "bar")
>>> "-".join(new_file_name)
'foo-bar'
```

You can use an empty string if you don't want to introduce any new characters in the resulting string. `"".join` would just glue the strings together.

```
>>> "".join(new_file_name)
'foobar'
```

While it's possible to call it more like an ordinary function, by passing the joining string as the first argument to `str.join`, this would be highly unorthodox.

```
>>> str.join("-", new_file_name)
'foo-bar'
```